# Appending is not happening in XML tag

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs, extjs6

I have a xml data which is given below.

```
<Sports>
<Oplympics>

    <CONT Team="All" Country="Some" FLG = "0">
        <TeamData Data="1" Data="2" Data="3"/>
    </CONT>


    <CONT Team="Aus" Country="Australia" FLG = "0">
        <TeamData Player="X1" Player2 = "X2"/>
    </CONT>

    <CONT Team="Eng" Country="England" FLG = "0">
        <TeamData Player="Y1" Player2 = "Y2"/>
    </CONT>
</Oplympics>
```

What I want is to take a first tag of `TeamData` from CONT and add to all the CONT from 2nd to end. The sample output will be like

```
<Sports>
<Oplympics>

    <CONT Team="All" Country="Some" FLG = "0">
        <TeamData Data="1" Data="2" Data="3"/>
    </CONT>


    <CONT Team="Aus" Country="Australia" FLG = "0">
        <TeamData Player="X1" Player2 = "X2"/>
        <TeamData Data="1" Data="2" Data="3"/>
    </CONT>

    <CONT Team="Eng" Country="England" FLG = "0">
        <TeamData Player="Y1" Player2 = "Y2"/>
                    <TeamData Data="1" Data="2" Data="3"/>

    </CONT>
</Oplympics>
```

I am trying this code. Here I am getting TeamData and then in for loop it is setting for first element but second it is not entering in loop. Am I missing anything. Can any body please help

```
var TeamData = Xml.getElementsByTagName('CONT')[0];
var CONTTag = Xml.getElementsByTagName('CONT');
                for(var i=1; i<CONTTag.length-1; CONTTag++){
                    CONTTag[i].append(TeamData);
                }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error 'Xml.getElementsByTagName('CONT').[0];' remove the .[0] should be Xml.getElementsByTagName('CONT')[0];

Comment: @WalksAway Ya that is fine. I remove that. This happened when I was typing code. I edited. ANy Suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with you code:

1. Syntax error in the first line - remove the '.' between closing
   bracket and opening square bracket.
2. The TeamData variable doesn't actually contain the TeamData node - the selector needs to be changed.
3. The loop should start at 1, not zero, as the first CONTTag node is the one you are copying from.
4. The loop should increment i, not CONTTag.

Here is your code with those fixes in place:

```
var TeamData = Xml.getElementsByTagName('TeamData')[0];
var CONTTag = Xml.getElementsByTagName('CONT');
for (var i = 1; i < CONTTag.length; i++) {
  CONTTag[i].append(TeamData.cloneNode());
}
```

A couple of other general comments:

1. Your XML is missing a closing tag.
2. XML nodes shouldn't have attributes with duplicate names - so your TeamData node is invalid XML at the moment.

Comment: What is the meaning of the 2nd. 2.The TeamData variable doesn't actually contain the TeamData node - the selector needs to be changed. Can you please elobrate

Comment: Also by applying this I am getting `<TeamData Data="1" Data="2" Data="3"/>
` only in last tag not in all.

Comment: Xml.getElementsByTagName('CONT') will return an array of CONT nodes.  So Xml.getElementsByTagName('CONT')[0] is just grabbing the first CONT node out of that array (not the first child node).

Instead you need to grab an array of the TeamData nodes, and then retrieve the first one.

Comment: I've just updated the code slightly - I'd switched out Xml for document when I was testing your code. Try my updated version.